# how to write floor function vectors in polar coordinates

Tags: vectors, polar-coordinates, ceiling-and-floor-functions

let $$\lfloor{x}\rfloor=y$$
And $$z=x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor$$
Plot the following vector in polar coordinates:

$$x\hat{\imath}+(y/z)\hat{\jmath}$$
I know that while transforming from cartesian to polar we substitute$$ x=r\sin{\theta}$$ and $$y=rcos{\theta}$$
But here the floor function and the vector form in polar coordinate pose sufficient difficulty for me to proceed.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simplify it at all, $\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\lfloor{r\cos(\theta)}\rfloor$ in polar coordinates. Just substitute for $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ to get your answer.

Comment: how can we plot $$y=\lfloor{x}\rfloor$$ in polar coordinates.Also how do we get the vector form?

Comment: Just substituting. You get $r\sin(\theta)=\lfloor{r\cos(\theta)}\rfloor$

Comment: @TheGreatDuck What makes you think that